# Building a chess diagram with css

Tags: css

Trying to build a chess diagram with just css3, but seems like my result is far from correct (for now, just a line of 4 cells) :

- cells seems to have margin different from 0
- cells are not squares, though I've used box-sizing css property

What did I misunderstand ?

My html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .chess_board {
      display: block;
    }

    .chess_cell {
      display: inline;
      font-family: serif;
      font-size: 2.3em;
      width: 0.8em;
      height: 0.8em;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .white_cell {
       background-color: rgb(217, 245, 2);
    }

    .black_cell {
      background-color: rgb(89, 34, 21);
    }

    .white_piece {
      color: rgb(179, 48, 63);
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    My chess board
    <div class="chess_board">
      <div class="chess_cell black_cell">&#9818;</div>
      <div class="chess_cell white_cell white_piece">&#9813;</div>
      <div class="chess_cell white_cell">&#9818;</div>
      <div class="chess_cell black_cell white_piece">&#9813;</div>
    </div>
    My another chess board ... to be drawn !
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `1. e2-e4 e7-e5` Wouldn't an HTML table more appropriate for a chessboard? With `td`, `th` and `scope="col"` or `row` for 1..8 and a..h

Comment: How ! I did it in the wrong way ! You're right indeed ! So used to hear that tables are evils that I forgot them ! Thanks :)

Comment: HTML tables used for layout purposes are evil. Data tables are legit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one thing you should know is that when you have an element with a `display: inline`, neither width nor height properties work. To make the elements line up, but still keep it's sizing, use `display: inline-block` instead.

Second, the "margin" isn't margin at all, but is caused by the spaces in between your squares. To fix this, you could either have there be no white-space in your html, like this:

```
<div>
... content
</div><div>
... content
</div>
```

or you could put a `float: left` on the squares.

Comment: Ok, replacing inline with inline-block keeps the square size good, but this time, the font piece is overlapping partly outside the box (also tried to reduce the font size). Do you know if this new problem can be solved ? (Anyway you solved the original problem).

Comment: does the cell have to be 0.8em?

Comment: For the 0.8em, it is just a test value. It can be changed, even if the new overlapping problem is the same. As for the cells gap, I found the solution by using display: block and float: left (I will have to use float:clear at a given line with a new class ...). Also, if I remove with and height specification, the size ratio is not good (not a square any more !).

Comment: While waiting on your example, also managed a better solution than my first attempt : http://pastebin.com/QNr2qKv3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80713/discussion-between-azzie-rogers-and-loloof64).

Answer (score 1):

I made [chess font](https://github.com/vasiliyaltunin/chess-merida-font), it use webfont and css like FontAwesome.

And also here a [demo](https://vasiliyaltunin.github.io/chess-merida-font/examples/chessboard-interactive) with chessboard